# Рельеф (в архитектуре) может портретировать кого-л.?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Мужской рельеф портретирует одного из учителей церкви и хозяина дома
>   сего – апостола Пуда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Рельеф, исполненный с безусловным портретным сходством, представляет одного из учителей церкви и хозяина дома сего — ап. Пуда.*

Мужскому портрету — да, мужскому (женскому) рельефу — нет.

Answer (score 1):

Мужской рельеф **изображает портрет** одного из учителей церкви и хозяина дома сего – апостола Пуда.

Портретировать – создавать портрет,  в других значениях слово не употребляется.